# Форма и надпись

Tags: html, php

Вот исходный код:

```
  <html>
  <head>
    <title>Главная страница</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php $test=$_POST[text]; echo "Вы ввели:".$test; ?>
  <form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" value="Введите текст здесь..." name="text">
    <input type="button" name="button">
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Отображается: Вы ввели: //Тут форма(текст и кнопка)

А мне надо чтобы до отправки была просто форма, а после просто надпись "Вы ввели <переменная из формы>"

Comment: @Семен пожалуйста оформляйте код красиво (да и не только код...)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я так понял что "сначала" и "потом" относятся к "до нажатию на кнопку" и "после нажатия на кнопку". Соответственно должно быть так:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Главная страница</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php if (!isset($_POST["text"])) { ?>
        <form action="" method="POST"> <input type="text" value="Введите текст здесь..." name="text">
            <input type="button" name="button" />
        </form>
<?php } else {
            echo "Вы ввели:".$_POST["text"];
} ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Вероятно, вы имели ввиду if (!isset($_POST["text"]))

Comment: Я это и хотел сказать)

Исправил

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Главная страница</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="POST"> <input type="text" value="Введите текст здесь..." name="text">
            <input type="button" name="button" />
        </form>
        <?php echo "Вы ввели:".$_POST["text"]; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: просто местами поменять что ли?

Comment: кстати не работает

Comment: ну да, последовательность, последовательность и ещё раз последовательность файла.

Comment: А ты точно свой файл обозвал "index.php" и запускаешь этот файл НЕ через браузер на прямую?))

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Главная страница</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="POST"> <input type="text" value="Введите текст здесь..." name="text">
            <input type="button" name="button" />
        </form>
            <?php

if(isset($_POST['button']))
{ $text = $_POST['text'];
if($text == '')
     echo 'Заполни поле';
else
     echo $text;

}
?>
</body>
```

</html>